# How do I remove a table in a nested table structure in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a nested table structure, where I want to delete a table inside.

Example:

```
for k, v in pairs (data) do                
   local element = v
      for i=1, #element do
              if (element[i].ttype == "ENUM") then
              -- Do Something
              -->Delete it!       
      end
 end
```

I can set it to nil, but this didn't 'remove' it. I would like to have that it removes it and adapt the rest of elements to the new index. Is there something in lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `table.remove()` function for lists.
Be careful doing this from inside the loop because your list length will change dynamically.  You'll probably have to check for `nil` manually or use a `while` loop instead.

See here: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.remove

Comment: So it would be table.remove(element[i],i) ?

Comment: `table.remove(element,i)`